Why am I getting a "CommandError: Project root directory not found..." when setting up an app code in VS Code with Native React?
I'm trying to run npx expo install react-native-web react dom and keep getting this error returned:
CommandError: Project root directory not found (working directory...)

Any insight as to what I am doing wrong here?
I tried running the npx command to install expo in react native in VS code.

First you need to start a project by running this command:
npx create-expo-app@latest

Then you can run:
npx expo install expo-dev-client


It means that you are not running your command in your project directory. As you mentioned that you are using VS Code, Open project then open terminal and run command
